# QT: Could not decode "filename.cpp" with"System"-encoding

Tags: qt, encoding, decode, corruption

So i'm working on a personal project using QT 4.7. In the middle of one of my builds, ubuntu 11.10 decided to crash. This version of ubuntu has crashed on me a couple of times in the past, but never has it done so in the middle of a QT- build.

Upon rebooting my system and opening my project in Qt again, I have found that my "mainwindow.cpp" file cannot be decoded, and my mainwindow.ui file "cannot be opened". The rest of my files (main.cpp, and mainwindow.h) are perfectly fine. I also have a couple of other classes that are perfectly in tact.

I have tried all of the different encoding options that QT provides, but none of them work. All I get is a big wash of incomprehensible characters. I go to the command line and I type:

```
file -i mainwindow.cpp
```

and get
    mainwindow.cpp: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
I do the same with mainwindow.ui and I get the same thing
    mainwindow.ui: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

for more info, the normal .cpp files return this:
    file -i main.cpp
    main.cpp: text/x-c; charset=us-ascii

I am assuming this means my files are in binary for some reason and I have no idea how to get them restored. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a backup somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your files were corrupted during the crash.

You may want to look at your .cpp files with a hex editor to see how corrupted it is. If it's only a few bytes (out of ascii range) you could manually fix them. If it's damaged in more than a few places, you may need to start over or use a backup.

Comment: Yup. Looks like both the files are completely corrupt. According to hex editor, most everything is now a bunch of periods and random ascii chars. Luckily I wasn't too far along in the project.

Comment: Since you're a new user and I want all the points I can get: If the answer was helpful, you should upvote it. If the answer resolves your issue, you can also accept the answer.